# Radio button validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a form in which a radio button click event check the value of other form's element. I want radio will be checked or unchecked depands upon the value of others.
My HTML

```
<input id="pDisplayPrice1" name="pDisplayPrice" type="radio" value="yes" onclick="displayPriceFormat();">
<span class="help-inline">Yes</span>
<input id="pDisplayPrice2" name="pDisplayPrice"  type="radio" value="no" >
<span class="help-inline">No</span>
```

and disPriceFormat() function is

```
function displayPriceFormat() {
    var areaPing = 0;

    var areaPerUnitPrice = $("#pPerUnitPrice").val();
    if (areaPerUnitPrice != "") {
        var areaPerUnitPriceUnit = $("#pPerUnitPriceUnit").val();
        var areaShow = areaPerUnitPrice + '/' + areaPerUnitPriceUnit
        areaPing = 1;
    }

    if (areaPing != 0) {
        // radio button will be checked
    } else {
        //radio button will unchecked

    }
```

i have tried

```
<input onclick="displayPriceFormat(e);"/>
<script>
 ......
  e.preventDefault(); /// return false;
 .......
</script>
```

Comment: where is your `#pPerUnitPrice` ? it seems that you have wrong id

Comment: var x = $("#pDisplayPrice1").checked;  var y = $("#pDisplayPrice2").checked;  ,Check value of x,y and On submit event of form apply validations accordingly

Comment: or directly you can write this
if($("#pDisplayPrice2").attr("checked")){ //enter your code }

Comment: @AwladLiton, it is giving correct message on alert(areaPing) in if and else condition

Comment: it should alert 0 because you do not have any input with id `pPerUnitPrice`

Comment: @AwladLiton My form have that element .....

Comment: You want radio be checked ON_RADIO_CLICK according to other element value... OR radio be checked ON_OTHER_ELEMENT_CHANGED?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see  any html input which id is : `pPerUnitPrice`
you have used it in this line:

```
  var areaPerUnitPrice = $("#pPerUnitPrice").val();
```

But i think below info will help you :

you can check a checkbox is checked or not check like this:

```
    if($("#id_of_checkbox").attr("checked")){ 
    //checked
    }
   else {
    //unchecked

   }
```

you can check a check box like this:

```
$("#id_of_checkbox").prop('checked',true);
```

you can check a uncheck box like this:

```
$("#id_of_checkbox").prop('checked',false);
```